# How to REQUEST_URI ARGS or Params Dynamic in ModSecurity

Tags: dynamic, rules, args, mod-security, request-uri

Example url
/outlet/?filter_cor=linho,metalizado,caramelo,bordo,listrad

I would like to know if it is possible to make a rule in modSecurity that where are the arguments "linho,metalizado,caramelo,bordo,listrad" if the names are changed he accepts the same rule

SOLVED

SecRule REQUEST_URI "@contains outlet/?filter_cor" "id:1,phase:1,deny,status:409,msg:'Denied'"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly.
But if you want to check a list of alternatives in arguments, you can do it like this:

```
SecRule ARGS:filter_cor "@rx ^(?:linho|metalizado|caramelo|bordo|listrad)$" "log,auditlog,phase:1,id:1,t:lowercase,msg:'some text',block"
```

Comment: In fact, this is a Wordpress filter url, I would like to block this url, regardless of the values chosen in it, because the filter does not exist and is consuming a lot of CPU on the host